# Drupal 7 custom content type display rules

Tags: drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 website (which I did not built) with pages made out of 1 specific custom content type (let's call it custom-content). So my pages are like this:

```
Url: site/very_seo_friendly.url
Page
\- header
\- sidebar
\- 1 or many items of custom-content
\- footer
```

Unfortunately the site also allows for the page to display as such (after editing for example):

```
Url: site/custom-content/custom-content-title <- also indexed by search engines
Page
\- header
\- Related content sidebar with all custom-content items listed
\- 1 specific custom-content item
\- footer
```

When I add new custom-content I need to select under which page this custom-content belongs to. Is there a way to prevent drupal from displaying that custom-content item alone? I can do web server redirection to block those urls but it'd be nicer if they didn't exist at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to prevent drupal from displaying that custom-content item alone?**

yes!

There is a contributed module named "rabbit hole" which allows you to control the node view of contents. As per its documentation, it's configurable per bundle/content type.

Here is the link:
https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

Comment: Thank you very much! I installed the module but am a bit struggling to find where/how to configure it. There's apparently no doc available and in the module list only permissions setting is available. It's a bit late here so I'll continue looking tomorrow. Thanks again.